# pyspark-2.3 sparkml LogisticRegression model load issue

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am doing a sample pyspark ml exercise where I need to store a model and read it back. I am able to successfully save the model, but when I am trying to read/load it back it is throwing below exception. I am new to spark ml and python, please guide me on this.

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import RFormula
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import TrainValidationSplit
from pyspark.ml.tuning import TrainValidationSplitModel


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LocalMLSparkSession").master("local").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json("/to_data/simpleml.json").orderBy("value2")

df.select(df.color).distinct().show(10, False)

train, test = df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])


rForm = RFormula()
ls = LogisticRegression().setLabelCol("label").setFeaturesCol("features")

# setting pipeline
stages = [rForm,ls]
pipeline = Pipeline().setStages(stages)


#setting param grid builder
params = ParamGridBuilder()\
     .addGrid(rForm.formula,["lab ~ . + color:value1", "lab ~ . + color:value1 + color:value2"])\
     .addGrid(ls.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])\
     .addGrid(ls.regParam,[0.1, 0.2])\
     .build()

#setting evaluator
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()\
            .setMetricName("areaUnderROC")\
            .setRawPredictionCol("prediction")\
            .setLabelCol("label")

#checking hyperparameters to train datasets
tvs = TrainValidationSplit()\
    .setTrainRatio(0.75)\
    .setEstimatorParamMaps(params)\
    .setEstimator(pipeline)\
    .setEvaluator(evaluator)


tvsFitted = tvs.fit(train)

evl = evaluator.evaluate(tvsFitted.transform(test))

tvsFitted.transform(test).select("features", "label", "prediction").show(10,False)

print(evl)
pip_model = tvsFitted.bestModel
pip_model.write().overwrite().save("/to_path/sparkml/model")

model = TrainValidationSplitModel().load("/to_path/sparkml/model")
model.transform(test)
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dd/dd/python-workspace/SparkMLPipelineDemo.py", line 59, in <module>
    model = TrainValidationSplitModel().load("/to_path/sparkml/model")
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bestModel'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove parenthesis when you load, e.g. replace :

`model = TrainValidationSplitModel().load("/to_path/sparkml/model")`

with

`model = TrainValidationSplitModel.load("/to_path/sparkml/model")`

Comment: I tried with the code changes you mentioned getting pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.TrainValidationSplitModel but found class name org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel'

Comment: Oh didn't see this. You are trying to load TrainValidationSplitModel with PipelineModel object. Use PipelineModel.load("/to_path/sparkml/model") instead

Comment: I tried with  .. getting this error ...  model = PipelineModel().load("/to_data/sparkml/model")
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'stages'